# How can i remove language subfolders in URLs and have those page redirect to the non-language version

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localization, internationalization

i have 3 versions of every page, one in English, one in French, one in Russian, so;
- www.example.com/page
- www.example.com/fr/page
- www.example.com/ru/page

What .htaccess rewrite rule or RegEx would I need if i want to redirect the /fr/ and /ru/ pages into their English counterparts?

e.g www.example.com/fr/page > redirects to www.example.com/page

The pages are identical, just translated, so I just want to redirect the 2 language URLs into the main English versions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Some tests:

- `https://www.example.com/fr/page` is [redirected](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a283feb1-845e-4977-9682-10f87f6d11cd) to `https://www.example.com/page`
- `https://www.example.com/ru/new` is [redirected](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a76e51fb-ed40-4378-bdbf-db72fba372dd) to `https://www.example.com/new`